# Why does magit-git-lines differ from git output in this case?

Tags: magit, process

```
~/github/hub $ git rev-parse HEAD
4777bd363058213605ebb292b35ef1a6edb3663c

~/github/hub $ git --no-pager log \
                --grep='\[ci skip\]' --invert-grep \
                --format=oneline --max-count=1
cbf7ab1ba3fa91287085ce0cbebdc11c84388888 Improve `hub merge` to not generate leftover remote refs

~/github/hub $ (magit-git-lines "log"
                "--grep='\\[ci skip\\]'" "--invert-grep"
                "--format=oneline" "--max-count=1")
("4777bd363058213605ebb292b35ef1a6edb3663c Update `merge` documentation")
```

The repository I'm working with is [github/hub](https://github.com/github/hub).  I can only assume I'm misapplying the arguments, but I can't see my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`magit-git-lines` does not run a shell, so you don't need the single quotes to protect the argument value.

```
(magit-git-lines "log"
                 "--grep=\\[ci skip\\]" "--invert-grep"
                 "--format=oneline" "--max-count=1")
```

Comment: Ah, did the single quotes get passed literally to `process-file`? That'd explain it. Thanks!